# C++ how can function parameter access private-declared classvariables?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

in the following code, how come I can access the private member int a[] inside the parameter-object v?

```
bool Arr::operator==(const Arr &v)
{
  if( size != v.size)
        return false;
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)

    if( a[i] != v.a[i])
        return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you see that `Arr::` in front of your operator member? You realize your operator is also a member function of the *same class as the parameter*., right? Privacy only applies to derivations and the outside world (and even there, can be overridden by friending).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/access-rules.html

> - A member (either data member or member function) declared in a private section of a class can only be accessed by member functions
>     and friends of that class
> - A member (either data member or member function) declared in a protected section of a class can only be accessed by member functions
>     and friends of that class, and by member functions and friends of
>     derived classes
> - A member (either data member or member function) declared in a public section of a class can be accessed by anyone

Note that it refers to classes, not to object instances.

Answer (score 0):

A member function of some instance of class `X` can also access the private members of other instances of `X`, not just its own. Otherwise there would be no way of implementing assignment operators or copy constructors.